# How to regenerate exe file in debug path in c# wpf .netcore application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core

My application is missing exe file in bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1

How do I regenerate or build another in visual studio. I tried rebuilding too but it does not work.

[image: Debug profile does not exist]

Comment: Already tried a clear and rebuild project?

Comment: Hav you checked 'x86' and 'x64' sub folders?

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind and it works, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the project and restarting VS.

Try creating a new [WPF.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/get-started/create-app-visual-studio?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Check your antivirus software, maybe your exe was accidentally deleted by the antivirus software.

Finally if it still doesn't work, try to repair your vs.

Comment: Hi Santosraj, May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?